# emacs on windows 7 : Failed to download 'melpa-stable' archive

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am trying to configure Emacs for Clojure on a Windows 7 machine and I get this error message which I did not get on macOS:

```
Failed to download 'melpa-stable' archive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the proxy server was blocking the http request.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue in windows in general, this is due to not be able to connect via https to solve this, download gnutls dependencies and unzip to your emacs folder there is a zip with gnutls and other utilities

http://gnu.mirror.globo.tech/emacs/windows/emacs-25-x86_64-deps.zip

this will work with emacs 25

http://gnu.mirror.globo.tech/emacs/windows/emacs-25.3_1-x86_64.zip

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In your Emacs config file, do you have the following at the top of it?

```
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```